# How to automatically accept the "Open/Save Dialog" in a WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, download, webbrowser-control

I am working on a c# Windows utility, which is opening a file using webbrowser control.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("URL");
```

URL is actually an attachment, which is showing as "Open" "Save" dialog

```
private void WebBrowser1_FileDownload(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    textbox1.text ="filedownload event fired!!"
}
```

can I do somthing so that i cancel the file open/save dialog in the background.

As I wanted to automate the process and don't want user to get popped up message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392156/c-sharp-winform-avoid-two-message-box

Comment: Should probably just download the file directly (eg. using WebClient) ..